# How can i add diffrent sizes of the same product?

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a function where i can add products to my shopping cart. The problem is that when i add one product at a time, from different product that is, it works. But when i try to add the same product in different sizes i get this error, how do i fix this?.

```
    def add_cart_size(request, product_id, product_size):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    product_size = ProductSize.objects.get(pk=product_size)
    print('size', product_size)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id=_cart_id(request)
        )
        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart, size=product_size.name)  # noqa:501
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            quantity=1,
            cart=cart,
            size=product_size.name
        )
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('cart_detail')


def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id=_cart_id(request)
        )

        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            quantity=1,
            cart=cart
        )
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request, total=0, counter=0, cart_items=None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
            counter += cart_item.quantity
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    return render(request, 'cart/cart.html', dict(cart_items=cart_items, total=total, counter=counter))  # noqa:501


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
    if cart_item.quantity > 1:
        cart_item.quantity -= 1
        cart_item.save()
    else:
        cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart_detail')


def cart_remove_size(request, product_id, size):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart, size=size)
    if cart_item.quantity > 1:
        cart_item.quantity -= 1
        cart_item.save()
    else:
        cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart_detail')


def cart_remove_product(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
    cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart_detail')


def cart_remove_product_size(request, product_id, size):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart, size=size)
    cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart_detail')
```

This is the error i get

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /cart/cart/add/25
get() returned more than one CartItem -- it returned 2!
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: well, the error text says clearly that there are at least 2 objects, which satisfy the condition inside get(). But ii must be only one object, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get . Probably, you have saved same CartItem twice,

Answer (score 1):

If you have product sizes then probably your better with taking sizes instead of product.

Each size has different SKU correct? If not then product size is required from the request upon adding products to distinguish cart items and avoid multiple objects found.